# Codeigniter dynamic subdomain with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, dynamic, routes, subdomain

My codeigniter app need following url processing.

Url processing as follows in http.

```
mysite.com --->  mysite.com/index.php/web/
subdomain.mysite.com  -- > mysite.com/index.php/web/subdomain
www.subdomain.mysite.com --> mysite.com/index.php/web/subdomain
subdomain.mysite.com/dddd --> mysite.com/index.php/web/subdomain/dddd
```

I uses following code working, But it doesnt work with www.subdomain.mysite.com

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

#Wildcard subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).mysite.com    
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ mysite.com/en/site/%1/$1 [P,L,QSA]

#end Wildcard subdomains

#default CodeIgniter rules to ignore index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

because both www and subdoamin taken as a one part. 
If anyone can help me will be appreciated.

If this can be with codeigniter coding also considerable.

Thanks